# When routing to error.html in Spring Boot, the logged in user seems to be cleared out

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication

I have a controller where I am trying to log the error details when the user is routed to error.html. The problem is that even if the user was logged in, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is returning null.

It seems like the context is being cleared when the user is routed to the error page. I'm not really sure where to begin from here. I did debug through this, and it seems to be getting cleared out in FilterChainProxy, but I don't know if that means anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Please do share more code samples so that we could have a better understanding of the issue at hand. @Relevant